# How to send data from jsp to servlet, while keeping the parameter that is being sent hidden?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

On the first jsp page I have a form that allows the user to enter some criteria to query users in the database. When the search button is pressed, the data is passed to a servlet that queries a database and returns a list of matching users with relevant information to display.

The servlet passes the data into an ArrayList and outputs it in a table in a jsp page. For each row there is a button that navigated to the user's personal profile page.

My implementation is that when the button is clicked, it passes the username to the servlet to query the database for the individual user's data. I did this through a link source

> href="Servlet?username=<%= user.username%>.

But this displays the username in the url. I also tried using a form with hidden parameters, but that doesn't seem right as it shows up in the jsp code in the developer console.

Is there a way to pass the username in such a way to not show it to the user? Or am I misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: Use `POST` not `GET`  this is achieved by using a html form and a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of using hidden `<input>` parameters in a POST request is correct. There is nothing wrong with it here because you're responding to a user's selection; so, they already know what username is being passed to the *servlet* as they selected it.

But, you would definitely not pass it as a query parameter in a GET request because then the users could bookmark profiles directly, or someone could use that URL with a script to collect valid usernames etc. POST requests are harder to simulate that way.